# Error calling Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm getting an error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SPVALIDATEDBA'

while trying to call the stored procedure spValidateDBA from inside a C# function.

**C# code**

```
string sConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;User ID=system;Password=system;";
            OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(sConnectionString);
            OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("spValidateDBA", myConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "spValidateDBA";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
            myCommand.Parameters["UserId"].Value = txtUsrId.Text.ToUpper().ToString();
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserRole", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;               
            var rolechk = false;
            string checkrole = "DBA";   
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteReader();
// this is where i'm getting the error "PLS-00306: wrong number
// or types of arguments in call to 'SPVALIDATEDBA'"
```

**Stored procedure spValidateDBA**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
    UserId IN VARCHAR2,
    UserRole OUT STRING_ARRAY)
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select GRANTED_ROLE bulk collect into UserRole from DBA_USERS DU,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS DRP where DU.USERNAME=UserId AND DU.USERNAME=DRP.GRANTEE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select USERNAME into UserIdOut from DBA_USERS where USERNAME=UserId';
END spValidateDBA;
```

STRING_ARRAY is of string array type as declared in this statement:

```
CREATE TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Comment: You could try by naming your parameters with the parameter prefix required by Oracle `:UserId` and `:UserRole`

Comment: Could you please explain Steve..!!

Comment: `myCommand.Parameters.Add(":UserId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);` , same for UserRole

Comment: I think the String_Array may be the problem.  Try declaring the UserRole OUT VARCHAR2.  The parameter Name may be the problem as Steve Explained

Comment: @user3294517 -- UserRole is supposed to hold a collection of string values,that's why i had declared it as such..declaring it as varchar2 is resulting in an error,in which case UserRole can contain only value of type varchar2,not a collection of values as desired.any other suggestions?

Comment: @Steve -- i edited my code per your suggestion,now i'm getting a different error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the line "myCommand.Parameters["UserId"].Value = txtUsrId.Text.ToUpper().ToString();"

any suggestions please?

Comment: Make sure txtUsrId has a value and is not null.

Comment: txtUsrId is getting populated through textbox,so during runtime it will always have some value...

Comment: You should change also the Indexer to the same name used when you add the parameter `myCommand.Parameters[":UserId"].Value ....`